# How do I access the presenting view controller in the preview actions of a 3D touch peek action?

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing 3D touch peek/pop actions on cells in a UICollectionView. I added preview actions to the peek presentation, one of which is delete. So, I would now like to delete the cell from the collection view.

Since the data source is a singleton available to the presented view controller (the one being peeked), I can easily delete the cell; however, I need to then reload the collection view (which is immediately presented after the preview action is selected and the peek goes away). However, it seems that viewWillAppear is not called when the presenting view controller becomes visible after the peek is dismissed (the preview action being selected). The closure arguments in the preview actions handler include only the presented view controller, not the presenting one.

So, how do I let the presenting view controller know it needs to update the collection view? Do I have to implement a delegate callback?

Thanks,

Yariv.

Answer (score -2):

Just call:

```
 self.collectionView!.reloadData()
```